# Is there way to integrate the jQuery function toggle class in react js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a jQuery function for toggling the class in custom.js.so I integrate all the CSS, and bootstrap custom.js in a public folder in HTML, but all the other files work fine but custom.js is not working so I install the jQuery library & import the jQuery  & custom.js in index.js but still the same problem. Is any other way to achieve this because I have more functions in custom.js.

```js
import $ from 'jquery;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".mobile-filter-btn").click(function () {
        $(".plp-filter").addClass("visible");
    });
    $(".mob-heading-close-btn").click(function () {
        $(".plp-filter").removeClass("visible");
    });
 }
```

```html
 <script type="text/jsx" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/jsx" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: If this is all you're using jQuery for, then it makes sense just to do it natively.

Comment: But I have 50-60 functions in the custom.js file which is written in jQuery all are provided by the teammate who is handling the design part. in the future, he will provide more code in jQuery for mobile responsive so that's why I need to integrate the custom.js (jQuery) into the code

Comment: The React documentation page on [Integrating with Other Libraries](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html).

*"The easiest way to avoid conflicts is to prevent the React component from updating. You can do this by rendering elements that React has no reason to update, like an empty <div />."*

Comment: okay is there any way to pass the jquery file globally on the full application because there is a lot of code in the file for different classes I have to write all the code in that component in which that design is written or on the official site they useing the class component in which the pass jquery in componentdidmount is it work for useEffect I am using functional component?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I assume that it works as expected, but the problem is, you are trying to put click handlers when components with those classes are not rendered yet.

You can put those jquery code into a function, import it to your react component and then use it in "componentDidMount" or useEffect with empty array of dependencies (works like componentDidMount in functional components) depending on which components you are using.

This way you will make sure that everything is rendered and you have where to put you click handlers.

To check this, try to console.log $(".mobile-filter-btn") in your code. I expect it to be undefined.

Also this is not good idea to bring jquery to react. It might work not very good with it and produce a lot of bugs or maintenance problems